# debian - iptables doesn't work for allowing one specific port

Tags: debian, iptables, routing, firewall

I have three virtual machines: A, B and C, all of them are running on debian. I have set up C to route traffic between A and B. Also C has two interfaces: `enp0s3` and `enp0s8`, not sure if it's important in this case. The routing works fine.

But now I want to set up iptables on the router to block all incoming requests except the ones that are sent to 8080 port.

Here is what I do:

```
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

But then if I try to connect to any port (including 8080) on B from A using `nc {host} {port}`, my input is not being translated from A to B.

I also tried it vice-versa:

```
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp ! --dport 8080 -j DROP
```

but it doesn't work either.

When I check the output of `iptables -L -v` there are some packets being accepted in `FORWARD` chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

This rule will allow forwarding of all packets going to port 8080
However packets from port 8080 (Responses to the SYN Packet) are not forwarded unless the port making the request is also port 8080. As mentioned in one comment this is most likely not the case!

You would need a second rule:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --sport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

this rule allows all packets comming from port 8080 to be allowed in forwarding

as a recommendation i would add the ip adresses of the machines to the rules if you need more security in your setup, as with these 2 rules someone could talk to a different port as long as his source port is 8080.

so my final rules would be:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --sport 8080 -s IPOFMACHINEA -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 8080 -d IPOFMACHINEA -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --sport 8080 -s IPOFMACHINEB -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 8080 -d IPOFMACHINEB -j ACCEPT
```

Since you didnt provide ips you will have to substitute them.

Comment: ICMP also needs to be permitted, especially MTU exceeded errors.